# Different Sharepoint filepaths in different environments

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sql, sharepoint, citrix

We have a VBA application in Excel (UserForm) that users use to update another excel workbook via SQL. The two files are side by side in an MS Sharepoint folder. There are two kinds of users – first group is using Citrix to remotely login to their Windows 7 (thin clients). The second group has notebooks and does not log in through Citrix at all.

Citrix users have no issues, everything works as intended both locally and remotely (although they have to always use the Open with Eplorer option from Sharepoint ribbon, but that's okay).

In case of notebook users, there is a strange issue with filepaths when they try to use the Sharepoint UserForm (locally it works fine) which result in an error as VBA can't find linked file:

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\https:\sharepoint-domain.com\Database.xls
```

Working path on Citrix goes like this:

```
\\sharepoint-domain.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Database.xls
```

Does anyone have a clue how to make this available for both groups of users?

Comment: Why can't notebook users use the citrix link? Are they not on the same network? Best I could think of is using a different function to detect the file with an `onerror` in it.

Comment: I was told they would need a different user account for Citrix... Which complicates it a lot. But I'll try what you suggested, thanks.